# Images not displyed on Tablet project

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have a QGIS project which I have uploaded to QField Cloud. QGIS displays all data collected on desktop including images, but the images are not showing in QField on my Tablet. This may have happened during a mis-guided sync. Running Synchronize on the Tablet updates any changes made to *.qgs and *.gpkg files in QGIS, but does not add the images/photos to the Tablet. I can see the images on the https://app.qfield.cloud site. How can I get the Tablet QField to synchronize (upload and display) the images on the Tablet??

Comment: I am also puzzled as to where the files are stored on Android device to enable off line display and collection

Comment: I have generated a new cloud project which looks good except it does not show the photos attached to project and visible on the cloud web site after synchronizing from the desktop..

Answer (score 0):

This is a puzzle
I have two projects, one cloud and the other offline.

They have identical layers, and the photo attributes settings are the same:

> ```
> Widget Type: Attachment
> Storage type: Select Existing file
> Default path: @Project_folder + '/photos'
> Store path as: Relative to Project Path
> Integrated Document Viewer: Type: Image
> ```

The offline project saves images in a project folder /photos and the Tablet and Desktop displays them as expected.

But the cloud project does not display the images. For some reason, on the cloud images are saved in a folder /DCIM.

Without editing the layer attributes (Default path: @Project_folder + '/photos'), I tried renaming the /photos folder /DCIM on the desktop project. After  synchronising, the project on the Tablet device displayed the images which were now in the /DCIM and not /photos .

With identical layer attributes why does the cloud save images in /DCIM whereas the offline version saves the images in /photos as defined in the layer Attributes?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).